# display value from combobox on different page in textbox

Tags: wpf

I am trying to display the selection from a combobox in a textbox on a different page when a button is clicked.  I thinking of using NavigationService, but I am not sure if that is the right way to go or not.  In this part of the code I am getting the correct value and for testing I am displaying in messagebox, and that is working.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        itemSelection = SubItemBox.Text;
        NavigationService.Navigate(
            new Uri("/Display.xaml?Message=" + itemSelection, 
                     UriKind.Relative)
            );

        MessageBox.Show(itemSelection);
    }
```

I am having an issue figuring out where to go next, I can't figure out how to get the itemSelection to dispaly in Display.xaml

```
namespace CateringDisplay
{

public partial class Display : Page
{

    string itemSelection;

    public Display()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


    }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am trying to learn WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using navigation, you could try the Event Aggregator (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx):

You define an event:

```
public class SelectionChangedEvent : PubSubEvent<string> { }
```

You subscribe to the event in the Display Page

```
public partial class Display : Page
{
    string itemSelection;

    public Display()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        IEventAggregator eventAggregator = Locator.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>();
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<SelectionChangedEvent>().Subscribe(OnSelectionChanged);
    }

    private void OnSelectionChanged(string obj)
    {
        itemSelection = obj;
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
```

The event handler updates your item selection using the event payload. Finally you fire the event from the button click event handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    itemSelection = SubItemBox.Text;

    IEventAggregator eventAggregator = Locator.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>();
    eventAggregator.GetEvent<SelectionChangedEvent>().Publish(itemSelection);

    MessageBox.Show(itemSelection);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: do i define the event as it's own item, or should define it on the same xaml.cs page where I have my Button_Click event?

Comment: The event is normally a class on its own. It can be referenced from several other classes.